# How to dynamically populate XElement (linq to xml)

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Is there a way I can dynamically add a new XElement to form child nodes as in the example below?

```
XElement xEl = new XElement(
                new XElement("Root",
                  // ** Is there a way I can do this:  
                 //  for(MyObject mObj in myObjects) {
                 //     if (IsXmlObj(mObj)){
                 //         new XElement(mObj.Name, mObj.Value);
                 //       }
                 //   }
                );
```

I would like to iterate through an object list to form the sub nodes.

What if I now modify the iterating part to become:

```
 //  for(MyObject mObj in myObjects) {
                 //     if (IsXmlObj(mObj)){
                 //         if (mObject.Name=="Small"){ mObject.Name="Big";}
                 //         new XElement(mObj.Name, mObj.Value);
                 //       }
                 //   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Select` this way:

```
var xEl = new XElement("Root",myObjects.Where(mObj=>IsXmlObj(mObj))
                                       .Select(mObj=> new XElement(mObj.Name, mObj.Value)));
```

Comment: this is a great solution! However I have modified the question to include an if statement